# Task is not executed

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, task

I am in an MVC application, and try to install a software in a remote server, by launching a WCF function in that server; WCF is hosted in a Windows service.

Since the installation process takes a long time, I execute it asynchronously, like this:

```
ChannelFactory factory = new ChannelFactory<MyClass>(binding, address);
MyClass channel = factory.CreateChannel();
Task task = new Task(() => { channel.LongTimeFunction(); });
task.Start();
```

In this way, the LongTimeFunction isn't executed at all.

It's the first time that I use the Task class, maybe there's something that I am missing?

Comment: Put a breakpoint into your lambda. Does it get hit? My guess: yes. Put a breakpoint into the server. Does it get hit? Can you see the webservice HTTP request in Fiddler?

Comment: Yes, the lambda is hit. Yes, I see the HTTP request in Fiddler, anyway if I just call the function without using a task it is executed without problems.

Comment: What does the server return? Is it performing the work you want? What error does it return? This is important to know to find out where the bug is. I want to know whether the client is sending something wrong to the server or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Starting a task you should wait for it to be completed,unless your code will be returned while the LongTimeFunction function is still not completed.
Here is a good example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: This is exactly what I need: launch the installation without waiting for its completion, so that the ui isn't blocked, and then maybe the user can regularly prompt the installation process to see if it has completed. But the function isn't even executed...

Comment: try this Task.Factory.StartNew(() => channel.LongTimeFunction());

Comment: add it to a tasks list and then wait for it to complete: Task.WaitAll(tasks);

Comment: I tried with StartNew, and then Task.WaitAll()  (without parameters), but the function is still not executed.

Comment: So, now I simply did: task.Start(); task.Wait(); and it worked! Thanks a lot for your help. I still don't understand why I have to wait for the task for it to work.

Comment: Each task represents a new thread of execution. A program has a main thread and OS gives each thread a quantum of time and then give the chance to other threads in the queue. Before your new thread which is actually the Task that you have started have the chance to get executed by OS your program main thread is completed and so the new thread is killed before it's even executed.